# Stack memory after pointer change

Tags: c, memory-management

Say I do this:

`const char *myvar = NULL;`

Then later

`*myval = “hello”;`

And then again:

`*myval = “world”;`

I’d like to understand what happens to the memory where “hello” was stored?

I understand it is in the read only stack space, but does that memory space stays there forever while running and no other process can use that memory space?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant

```
myval = "world";
```

instead, then

> I’d like to understand what happens to the memory where “hello” was stored?

Nothing.

You just modify the pointer itself to point to some other string literal.

And string literals in C programs are static fixed (non-modifiable) arrays of characters, with a life-time of the full programs. The assignment really makes the pointer point to the first element of such an array.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I understand that, but what happens with the memory area where "hello" is stored? Is it available for later use by the same app? say I have a long-running program, which does that a lot of times, will that make a memory leak?

Comment: @DavidVillasmil All strings are stored inside the program executable, and loaded into memory when the program is loaded. They stay in memory for the whole time the program is running. It's not part of the heap or anything that you can reclaim. Or anything that will leak.

Answer (score 0):

String literals have static storage duration. They are usually placed by the compiler in a stack pool. So string literals are created before the program will run.

In these statements

```
*myval = “hello”;

*myval = “world”;
```

the pointer myval is reassigned by addresses of first characters of these two string literals.

Pat attention to that you may not change string literals. Whether the equal string literals are stored as a one character array or different character arrays with the static storage duration depends on compiler options.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I understand that, but what happens with the memory area where "hello" is stored? Is it available for later use by the same app?

Comment: @DavidVillasmil See my appended post.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, let me put it this way: Is it available for later use by the same app? say I have a long-running program, which does that a lot of times, will that make a memory leak?

Comment: @DavidVillasmil Memory leaks occur when you are using objects with allocated storage duration and that were not freed by you.  So neither memory leak can occur with objects with the static storage duration. Objects with the static storage duration are alive during all the time of the program execution.